# LWJGL/opengl in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, netbeans, lwjgl

I cannot seem to import the opengl properly.

I am following this simple tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZKJC2cloIqc

As far as I understand, I have the correct jar and native files.

```
// I can import these
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;   

//I cannot however import this:
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLEXCEPTION;

//and gl methods such as this are not recognized:
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

I am using eclipse, I also have netbeans and am debating getting the intelij IDE being used in this tutorial if it will make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't Import GL11 to use gl methods (or other versions for certain methods )

You can use a static import so you don't have to put GL11 in front of every method or anything else

Comment: so how do I do that? Is it in the jar/natives I have or do I have to download it?

Comment: It's in the lwjgl jar, i don't know the exact import though at the moment. Write GL11.glBegin() somewhere and press ctrl + shift + o for organize imports. You can remove the method call afterwards it will get you the import though

Comment: It is import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11; or import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.* for the static import where you don't have to put GL11 in front of every method